# disable client authentication for localhost in tomcat two-way ssl

Tags: tomcat, ssl

My server runs tomcat 7 with this connector:

```
<Connector port="443"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/xml,text/js,text/css"
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="150"
       redirectPort="80"
       SSLEnabled="true"
       sslProtocol="TLS"
       scheme="https"
       secure="true"
       truststoreType="JKS"
        keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
        truststoreFile="trust.jks" truststorePass="changeit"
       keyAlias="myAlias"
       clientAuth="true"
    />
```

I have a tiny program on the server that has to communicate with my application but I don't want to include a certificate each time I make a request to my app.

How can I tell tomcat to exempt all localhost requests from providing a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just configuration, you can't.

You'd need to change clientAuth to want and then add a filter that rejected all requests that were not from localhost and did not present a certificate.

It might be easier to add a client cert to your local application.

Comment: I needed this phrase: "With just configuration, you can't."!